# Listing files without specific character in name on shell

Tags: shell, unix, ls

How to get a list of catalogs without specific character f. ex. "p"
I've tried:
`ls *[!p]*`
But "p" can appear in * and this option is useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your shell. A number of common ones support negative patterns as extensions to the POSIX glob syntax.

Given:

```sh
$ ls
a  b  c
```

`zsh` (Requires the `EXTENDED_GLOB` option to be turned on with `setopt` if not enabled already) and `tcsh`:

```sh
$ ls ^*b*
a  c
```

`bash` (Requires the `extglob` option to be turned on with `shopt` if not enabled already), `zsh` (Requires the `KSH_GLOB` and `NO_BARE_GLOB_QUAL` options to be turned on with `setopt`) and `ksh93`:

```sh
$ ls !(*b*)
a  c
```

Comment: When you have directories in the output of `ls !(*b*)`, you might want the option `-d`: `ls -d !(*b*)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can not use the wildcards that way. Also do not try to parse the `ls` with `grep -v`, never parse `ls` output (filenames with spaces, special characters and newlines).
Depending on the version of `find` you can use

```
find * -maxdepth 0 ! -name "*p*"
```